# How to Subtract a Variable By 1 Every Second?

Tags: python

I'm making a countdown clock, and I've got the basics down, but I have trouble trying to have a variable go down 1, every second. So here is an example:

```
countdownTime = 100
```

Now I want to be able to have this subtracted every SECOND while visible on screen. Here is another example:

```
print countdownTime
```

So while it is on the screen (or GUI), the variable is constantly going down one.

Also, how could I make a countdown by days?

Comment: Are you using a graphics library?

Comment: No, not of any I know about. I'm just using Python 2.7.10 if it helps.. I'm printing the variable (which would be a number in this case) on the screen. For example, New Years Eve countdown, except in Python.. And a lot simpler..

Comment: Btw we commonly speak of this as "decrementing".

Comment: Thank you. Is decrementing common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the time module?

```
import time
x = 100

while x > 0:
    print x
    x-=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from time import sleep

for i in reversed(range(100)):
    sleep(1)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the countdown to be separate from the rest of the code, then use a thread like so.

```
import time, thread
x = 100

def countdown(var):
    while var > 1:
        print var
        var -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

thread.start_new_thread(countdown, (x,))
```